# 404 error after checking browser cloudflare redirect url only

Tags: wordpress, nginx, cloudflare

Hello i have 404 error every time there is a browser check and gives an address like “https://www.mywebsite.com/?cf_chl_managed_tk=pmd_lJ44g7MrHYK29BtRBtcFUNNs3Dzo_LT21.viOSdeYXY-1631907472-0-gqNtZGzNAqWjcnBszRzR” no problem if the browser is not checked.

This is done on all pages !

I use WordPress for information and the error is displayed in WordPress.

I use also Nginx.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Edit: oddly in the admin it works the url "https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/index.php?cf_chl_managed_tk=pmd_lJ44g7MrHYK29BtRBtcFUNNs3Dzo_LT21.viOSdeYXY-1631907472-0-gqNtZGzNAqWjcnBszRzR" is displayed then is redirected to the correct url "https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/index.php"

If i desactive "Under attack Mode" all is work, but i absolutely have to keep it the site is always attacked!

Comment: solved by disabling Hide My WP

Comment: Updating the plugin fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the plugin Hide My WP fixed the problem.